# Use a button to call - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I'd like to use a delete button to call the delete row function in a TableView cell, just like the iPhone message app works.

The code I use to trigger this from a swipe will be familiar:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrayLocations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But how do I call this code/functionality when pressing say a red circular delete button in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want/should trigger this delegate yourself. Also remember that this delegate inserts / deletes cells so you need to check that editingStyle param. If you're adding a custom button you can simply route this to a custom method and delete the row.

Cell

- Button action hit
- Call a delegate

Table

- Get the index with indexPathForCell
- Adjust the data source array
- Call begin updating, delete row, end updating

Comment: Doing it manually isn't the issue. But it's that the commitEditingStyle method is rather subtle in that when you swipe it move the literals to the left, puts a delete button on the right and when you press it deletes the visible cell row. What I'm trying to figure out is how you trigger the same effect if you has a button on the left hand side just as in the iPhone Message App.